# How to open a webpage in the same window with javascript

Tags: button, mobile

This is the script for a webpage with a GO TO MOBILE SITE button. When the button is clicked I want it to go to the mobile site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function goMobile() {
      window.open("mobile.dudamobile.com/site/syedasadiq");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="submit" value="Go to mobile site" onclick="goMobile()" />
</body>
</html>
```

I'm certain that I've done everything correctly, but when I click the button on my browser it prodoces an error message saying: "Cannot find ...:/Users/AbdurRasheed/Desktop/mobile.dudamobil... Make sure path or Internet address is correct."

I think that the computer is registering my mobile URL as a file and not a website address, but I do not know for sure. Either way, how do I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href = "http://mobile.dudamobile.com/site/syedasadiq"`.

Comment: @user2627595 Glad it helped! Don't forget to accept when you can :)